# How to disable progress bar after taking a photo with camera?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, google-glass-camera

Is it possible, to disable the progress bar after taking a photo with camera (using Google Glass)?
I try to automatically take a photo every 2 seconds using Google Glass but when I am taking a photo while the progress bar is shown, the onActivityResult() method returns null.

**[EDIT 1]:**

I have no progress bar defined in my activity.xml layout, so I have no mProgressbar variable, where I could set `mProgressbar.dismiss()`

**Code:**

```
private fun takePicture() {
    val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {

    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val picturePath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_PICTURE_FILE_PATH)
        val bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.absolutePath)
        picture_imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Progress bar appears even in the case when I comment out every line in the onActivityResult() method.

Comment: Try mProgressBar.dismiss();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, have to call the camera directly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, after taking photo you can dismiss progressbar

```
ProgressBar.dismiss();
```

I hope this could help you